# What seasonings give ranch dressing its distinctive flavor?

Tags: seasoning, salad-dressing

I've always wondered this. Is there a collective set of seasonings that equal "ranch"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always thought it was the combination of mayonnaise and sour cream (or something like buttermilk) that gives ranch dressing that ever so slightly tang to it.

Then add in the seasonings like dill, pepper, and garlic and onion and you've got yourself something delicious.

Comment: actually, that may be the entire recipe for a good ranch dressing right there! :) i think it's all about the buttermilk and dill for sure.

Comment: and maybe add just a bit of thyme.